# Existence proof of infinite solutions of a diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove by construction that $x(x+1)=2 y^2$ has an infinite number of solutions where $x$ and $y$ are both positive whole numbers. Do not use an iterative procedure like that for solutions of Pell's equation in your proof.

Background: I came up with a proof of this years ago in which $x$ was a multiple of $32$ and a quadratic or quartic polynomial of an integer parameter. Given that, $x(x+1)/2$ was guaranteed to be a perfect square. I've since encountered another, probably better proof the above but efforts to find my old one have been in vain.

Proof using Pell:

1) Complete the square of the $x$ Side of the equation to get $x^2+x+1/4=2y^2+1/4$.

2) This is equal to  $(x+1/2)^2=2y^2+1/4$.

3)  Multiply both sides by $4$ to get: $(2x+1)^2=8y^2+1$.

4) Let $m=2x+1$ and $n=2y$. Then we have $m^2-2n^2=1$, Pell's Equation.

5) Given solution ($m,n$), construct a symmetric $2x2$ matrix with ($m,n \, \sqrt{2}$) as the first row.

6) The square of a symmetric matrix is symmetric. The determinant of the square of a matrix is the square of that matrix's determinant. We thus end up with two new integers in the first row ($m^2+2n^2, 2 \, m \, n$) which are again solutions of Pell's equation.

7) This can be iterated to generate a sequence of solutions.

8) $x$ and $y$ can be represented in terms of $m$ and $n$, so we thus have an infinite number of solutions for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: if someone tells you not to use Pell's equation, just ignore them!

Comment: You can drop the irrational numbers. Given positive integers with $u^2 - 8 v^2 = 1, $ you get a sequence of larger such from $$  (u,v) \mapsto (3u+8v, u+3v) $$ Here $u = 2x+1$ and $v=y$

Comment: Fun note. Suppose you have a sequence of 3 consecutive integers each expressible as a sum of two squares (a,b,c) where a is twice a perfect square and b is a perfect square, then the square root of b and half the square root of a are a solution to Pell's equation. Something similar applies to the case when a is a perfects square and c is twice a perfect square. In both cases there's a map to and from Pell's equation. So an infinite number of solutions to Pell implies and infinite number of triples of consecutive integers expressible as the sum of two squares. Eight always divides a. Hmm

Answer (score 1):

If you have one solution to
$x^2-dy^2 = 1$,
by using

$\begin{array}\\
(x^2-dy^2)(u^2-dv^2)
&=x^2u^2-d(x^2v^2+y^2u^2)+d^2y^2v^2\\
&=x^2u^2+d^2y^2v^2\pm 2dxuyv-d(x^2v^2+y^2u^2\pm 2xuyv)\\
&=(xu\pm dyv)^2-d(xv\pm yu)^2\\
\end{array}
$

you can construct 
an arbitrary number of them.

When $d=8$,
since
$3^2-8\cdot1^2 = 1$,
from this first solution
you can get
$u^2-8v^2
=(3u\pm 8v)^2-8(3v\pm u)^2
$.

Choosing "+"
gives Will Jagy's iteration.

Wow, is this not original.

Comment: Nevertheless, it comes from a pure heart

Comment: If only that were true. But I thank you anyway.